# Set up printing area until last row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have 300 different worksheets in a workbook and they all have different length. I need to print out all of them. I would like to use VBA to set printing area until last row of used range and print them because they all vary.

Column is the same until "I" column and row varies

please help !!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the following will help you achieve what you desire, it will loop through all your worksheets and find the last row with a value on Column I and then set the print area as such:

```
Sub PrintArea()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
'loop through all sheets in workbook
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    'get the last row with data on Column I
    ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:I" & LastRow
    'set print area from A1 to last row on column I
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: it worked for like 100 pages and after that, the rest is until page 4 and halfway through it was selected until page 8.. do you know why that is happening??

Comment: @KyleHong The code is actually looking for the last row with data on Column I, you might have to check them pages to see whether the last row is not where you actually expect it to be...

Comment: Thank, I think it must have been the formula, I changed it to count "C" coloumn which do not have any formula on it and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the sheets and set the print areas

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range

    For Each sh In Sheets
        With sh
            LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
            Set Rng = .Range("A1:I" & LstRw)
            .PageSetup.PrintArea = Rng.Address
        End With
    Next sh
End Sub
```